# Can't view my flag history on mobile if I have zero helpful flags due to entry failure

Tags: bug, mobile-web, flag-history

**Previous title:** The number above "helpful flags" cannot be clicked on mobile if it's zero, but I have pending flags

I raised a flag and I wanted to check it immediately. Of course within seconds it should be "pending", but as I navigated to my profile page, the number of "helpful flags" is zero, thus the number cannot be tapped on. It should be the entry to my flag history but I can't access it.
On an Android device with Google Chrome 57.

> [image: My profile page as of 10:30, 29 Apr, 2017 UTC]

However this bug is not present on the desktop site, only mobile.

**Edit**: My flag got marked as "helpful" so I'm finally able to view my flag history on mobile (but on MSE **only**). But I still think this is a bug that should be fixed.

Comment: Yeh, there *is* a link on the full site even if it is "0", no reason the mobile site shouldn't have.

Comment: It has been more than four years since you posted this. It is still not fixed.