# Always link to flag count

Tags: bug, flags, profile-page

I flagged something, and I don't know if it's declined or just pending because there's no link:

> [image: Screenshot from desktop website]

I have not edited nor voted on that site, but, in case it's relevant, I have one answer with 0 votes. I have checked and, on sites where I have only voted, I am able to see and click the "0 helpful flags".

If my flag is pending, I might want to retract it, and through my profile is the most convenient way.

I would like to be able to check on my pending (and declined?) flags as soon as I have any, which would look something like this:

> [image]

---

I now think this is a bug because Oded's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261787/323179) to the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199414/323179) Nathan Tuggy linked says:

> [The new profile] links to the flags page, even if none have been accepted yet.

Which isn't what happened.

Comment: Looks to be a specialization of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile, which apparently only kicks in if you have at least *something* in Impact.

Comment: Oded's answer to that linked question is correct *if* you have *other* contributions that show there... so if you have edits but no helpful flags it still links to the the flag page even though it says "0 helpful flags"...

Comment: ...but [not on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295352/307988). I saw this "Measure your impact" placeholder for the first time trying to repro that