# The case of the disappearing flag

Tags: support, flags, activity

On October 26th I raised a flag on one of the answers to this Meta question on Personal Finance & Money:

[Have there been any "Is this a scam?" questions that the answer was "No"?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/have-there-been-any-is-this-a-scam-questions-that-the-answer-was-no)

I raised a "Not An Answer" flag on one of the answers which I believed did not address the question. Yet when I look at my Activities page where flag history is normally shown, it is blank:

[image: Screenshot of Activities page]

Now you might think that I'm simply misremembering flagging the post. However, this post was discussed in another site's chatroom, and there are several comments there from me indicating that I flagged it.

[image: Screenshot of Chat]

When I checked back a few days later and saw that the flag had been declined, I even went back to that Chat to note it:

[image: Screenshot of Chat follow-up]

Now of course it is theoretically possible that I claimed to have flagged it and then went back a few days later and claimed that the flag was declined, but none of it had actually happened. However, even if we don't trust that line of evidence, there is other evidence that can be adduced here.

The same Activities page that shows no flag history, also shows that I have the Citizen Patrol badge:

[image: Screenshot of Activities page]

The Citizen Patrol badge is defined as:

> First flagged post.

So I clearly have raised at least one flag on the site.

Not only that, if I follow the link in the badge it shows me that I earned it on... October 26th:

[image: Screenshot of badge]

Most importantly, if I go to the very answer that I claim I flagged, and click on the flag button, it tells me that I have *already flagged it* as "Not An Answer":

[image: Screenshot of flag dialogue]

So, to summarize, I have comments indicating that I raised a flag, I have a badge indicating that I raised a flag, and I have a flag notice indicating that I raised a flag... yet my Activities page does not show any flag history.

### Why?

I might have thought that flag history is not shown when you only have one flag; however, this cannot be because the history was definitely displayed at some point (that's how I knew the flag was declined), and I have exactly one flag on other sites and the flag history *does* show:

[image: Screenshot of Activities page]

Comment: I made a bug/feature request a while ago to have this fixed: [Always link to flag count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/295374/323179). Yeah, the current behavior is confusing and dumb.

Answer (score 6):

Read carefully:

[image]

> 1 *helpful* flag

If you have no other history on the site, this history section will only display once you get at least one helpful flag. Since your flag was declined, it doesn't count, and the section won't display. You can still view your flag history on Money at https://money.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/78372, and the declined flag will show up there.

Comment: Interesting. However, since this is the first I'm hearing of the flag summary page, I must have been able to see the declined flag on the main activities page at some point, in order to know that it was declined.

Comment: @Alex or you tried to flag something else and got the "your previous flag was declined" warning.

Comment: @muru Not the case in this situation. I had never visited the site before raising the flag. It was only because someone linked the post in another chat room that I saw it and created the account in order to flag it. According to the calendar in my profile, before posting this question I had only visited the site one other time, which was on October 30th to check whether my flag had been accepted. There isn't anything else that would have prompted me to raise another flag.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199414/if-i-have-flagged-a-post-show-me-a-flags-link-in-my-profile allowed us to see a flag history of nothing but declines, so the "read carefully" admonition seems misplaced: it's really not intended to be so fiddly and nitpicky. That's a [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295374/always-link-to-flag-count).